# How to use Less than and equal to use for loop to build array in java

Tags: java

```
public static void loop_array_build1()
{
    int array_quantity = 12;
    int rd_1[] = new int[array_quantity];
    //Building
    for (int i = 1; i < array_quantity; i++)
    {
        rd_1[i] = i;
        System.out.println("Array building : " + rd_1[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Total array built -> " + rd_1.length);
    System.out.println("");

    //Showing
    for (int x = 1; x <= rd_1.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Array showing : " + x);
    }
}
```

1. I can not use Less than and equal(=<) because I want to build from 1 until 12, but if I use normal Less than(<)
   it's not error

   ```
   for(int i = 1; i < array_quantity; i++) << Not error
   for(int i = 1; i <= array_quantity; i++) << Error
   ```

Or I have to start array index at 0 only, not from 1?

2. When I print this line `System.out.println("Total array built -> " + rd_1.length);` It show array has 12,
   maybe it's depended on from these 2 line

   ```
   int array_quantity = 12;
   int rd_1[] = new int[array_quantity];
   ```

   How I can know really quantity array already were build, not in from index.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you ask...

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing in Java starts from 0. So, if `rd_1` has 12 elements, then you can address `rd_1[0]` to `rd_1[11]` inclusive.

Hence your `for` loop should be of the form

`for (int i = 0; i < rd_1.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't build from index 1 to 12 because array indexes count from 0 therefore 0-11. if you want these indexes to have the values 1-12 use`rd_1[i] = i+1;` and i starts at 0.

The following 2 lines instantiate the array with the given length which is 12. After this line, the array exists with 12 indexes with value `null`.

```
int array_quantity = 12;
int rd_1[] = new int[array_quantity];
```

The length is fixed to what you defined on instantiating the array and cannot be changed. If you want to know the amount of values which are actually set, you will have to count them like this:

```
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i : rd_1) {
        counter++;
    }
```

`counter` then holds the amount of values which are set

Answer (score 0):

Taking your snippet this would be the output, that means as other mentioned Array in Java starts from index 0, Hence if you don't use it will be zero

```
    // If you get the value of 0 index it will be 0
    System.out.println("rd_1[0] :- "+ rd_1[0]);
    //Output :- rd_1[0] :- 0

    // If you get the value of 11 index it will be 11
    System.out.println("rd_1[11] :- "+ rd_1[11]);
    //Output :- rd_1[11] :- 11

    // If you get the value of 11 index it will be 11
    System.out.println("rd_1[12] :- "+ rd_1[12]);
    //Output :- Exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because Array will have 0 to 11 index, 12index will not be there
```

So the correct snippet would be as below

```
public static void loop_array_build1()
{
    int array_quantity = 12;
    int rd_1[] = new int[array_quantity];
    for(int i=0;i<array_quantity;i++)//Building
    {
        rd_1[i] = i+1;
        System.out.println("Array building : rd_1["+i+"] -- "+rd_1[i]);
    }

}

Array building : rd_1[0] -- 1
Array building : rd_1[1] -- 2
Array building : rd_1[2] -- 3
Array building : rd_1[3] -- 4
Array building : rd_1[4] -- 5
Array building : rd_1[5] -- 6
Array building : rd_1[6] -- 7
Array building : rd_1[7] -- 8
Array building : rd_1[8] -- 9
Array building : rd_1[9] -- 10
Array building : rd_1[10] -- 11
Array building : rd_1[11] -- 12
```